# Create script for cockroach db daily backup to kubernetes to GCP storage

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cockroachdb

I have deployed Cockroach db database in google Kubernetes engine, and now i want to backup that database daily purpose. I want to backup database from Kubernetes and upload that database dump to my google storage bucket. Suggest me if anyone have any idea about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to perform a daily backup of a database in GKE. There are different approaches.

The easiest solution is to just write a little script that [executes pg_dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360853/how-to-backup-a-postgres-database-in-kubernetes-on-google-cloud) to [export](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-dump.html) the database directly to Google Cloud Storage. Containerize the script, run it as a job. Run the job everyday.

To run the job every day, you would have to write a [cron job pod](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs). Hence, the job will be performed every day. The database will be backed-up everyday.